# Jobs queue for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, rabbitmq, task-queue

### Background

Working on an Open Source project where we have many backend processing tasks, some heavy and some lightweight, coming at very high rate rate.

We have decided to use job queues to handle the different jobs, since with queues we could scale up consumers, therefore execute more jobs at a time, as well as guarantee the jobs will actually be performed even if worker crashes.

### Requirements

Reliability is important. We want to be able to make sure each job has been finished, even if the worker performed it crashed, the queue crashed or the system crashed.

We also want to be able to scale worker modules on an overloaded queues.

[From RabbitMQ's tutorial,](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)  I've seen it has reliable mode (for jobs, as well as for the channels, so if anything crash the job will not get lost) and supports scaling  exactly as I want, but it doesn't use Redis (which I can't tell if is a pro or a con).

I've also looked into Kue, but its API is quite cumbersome, and I couldn't tell right away if it suites to me.

I've also heard about Disque (from the author of Redis), Bull, Kafka and some more, and became confused of the amount of technology available.

Is anyone familiar with the different queues technologies and can tell what's the most suitable for the project, under the requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not Kafka - it's purpose is not a general job / work queue. it is a distributed even log and event queue, meant for other purposes (Event Sourcing, etc).

Otherwise, pick one and run with it. Kue or Disque or RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ or Gearman or whatever. They will all work well for you. They all have tradeoffs, but what you have described above doesn't tell me that any of the options are out of the question.

Personally, I prefer RabbitMQ. I like the centralized broker model, and having spent many years working in message queue systems, I like the way RabbitMQ bakes many of the patterns and practices of good distributed systems into it. I like the ability to manually acknowledge that a message has been processed, to remove it from the queue - or to have a process crash, and the message is returned to the queue. There's a lot to like about RabbitMQ, in my opinion.

But the other options are all fine. Just pick one and go.

(FWIW, I have a RabbitMQ for Node Developers training package available at http://rabbitmq4devs.com)

Comment: Thanks, the only drawback in Rabbit is that it's cenrtalized and I thought about giving a chance to decentralized technology that's built on top of Redis, such as Kue. Waiting to hear more about Kue - when you say it supports what I need, can you please detail a little further?

Comment: Redis is decentralized in the same way that RabbitMQ is: It's a distributed system. Redis + Kue also act the same as RabbitMQ, as a brokered message queue. You must connect to the broker - the RabbitMQ server - to send and receive messages. Redis and Kue work the same way. You connect to the redis server to send and receive messages

Comment: there's an interview / blog post i did on simpleprogrammer that talks about the main differences between redis and rmq: https://simpleprogrammer.com/2015/08/14/derick-bailey-is-a-messaging-master/

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't directly answers the question in comment. Kue seems to transport all jobs through the same queue (with createQueue method), and I can just specify the different jobs to pass - am I right? Because that's something I'd like to avoid.. I'd like to separate the jobs to be in different queues. In rabbit i'd just create multiple channels.

Comment: I see that Kue also has the "done" callback feature, to acknowledge jobs when they're done. So that's a good point already.

Comment: Finally, I've read that Kue is faster than RMQ? Is it right?